# Check jsp version with Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, version, factory

I wrote a jsp script to display Tomcat, Servlets and JSP versions.
I am using Eclipse / STS 4.

This is my script :

```
<%@page import="javax.servlet.jsp.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <h2>Hello World START !</h2>
   The current date is <%=new java.util.Date() %>
<br>
Tomcat Version : 
<%= application.getServerInfo() %><br>    
Servlet Specification Version : 
<%= application.getMajorVersion() %>.<%= application.getMinorVersion() %> <br>    
JSP Version:
<%= JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getEngineInfo().getSpecificationVersion() %>
</body>
</html>
```

Result of the previous code is as follow :

**Hello World START !

The current date is Sun Aug 14 17:21:46 CEST 2022

Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/10.0.21

Servlet Specification Version : 5.0

JSP Version: 3.0**

However, my code has two errors in my IDE :

line 1 : The import javax.servlet.jsp cannot be resolved.
line 14 : JspFactory cannot be resolved

I used **pom.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    

 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org         
 /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
 <groupId>com.incvision.springwebflow</groupId> 
  <artifactId>SpringWebFlowStart</artifactId> 
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>   

  <name>SpringWebFlowStart Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>SpringWebFlowStart</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

How to clean this code to remove indication error code in problems ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both your project and Tomcat 10 support Jakarta EE.
The javax.servlet package is part of Java EE. If you want that, modify your project and run on Tomcat 9.

From https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html:

*Apache Tomcat 10.0.x builds on Tomcat 9.0.x and implements the Servlet 5.0, JSP 3.0, EL 4.0, WebSocket 2.0 and Authentication 2.0 specifications (the versions required by Jakarta EE 9 platform).

[...]

Apache Tomcat 9.x builds on Tomcat 8.0.x and 8.5.x and implements the Servlet 4.0, JSP 2.3, EL 3.0, WebSocket 1.1 and JASPIC 1.1 specifications (the versions required by Java EE 8 platform).*

Comment: Really, you want to change `javax.servlet.xxx` to `jakarta.servet.xxx` when you are using Tomcat 10.x and later.

Comment: Whichever EE you decide for, both the container and the application have to match.

Comment: Tomcat can hot-deploy and hot-migrate an application from `javax.*` to `jakartax.*` which is a pretty amazing feature. It appears that the IDE is showing errors even though Tomcat would probably be able to properly-deploy this application.